# REGEX - How to find two hyphens in a filename?

Tags: regex, renaming

I'd like to search for filenames that contain two hyphens (only). Some filenames have one hyphen, I just want the one's with two hyphens in the name:

THIS: *some text - more text - yet more.txt*

NOT THIS: *some text - more text.txt*

The hyphens are always surrounded by a space, FWIW.

I tried using `(.*) - (.*) - (.*)` and a couple variants, but the results aren't what I am looking for. I either get nothing or filenames with just one hyphen when I try various combinations.

I know this is an obvious one, but I have tried wading through regex tutorials concerning *greedy*, *look aheads*, etc. but can't for the life of me solve this. Can anyone help? I'm not looking for just the solution--I'd like to understand what I'm doing wrong in the regex syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex,

```
^[^-]*(?:-[^-]*){2}$
```

This when written in expanded form will look like this,

```
^[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*$
```

Which is how you wanted it, but I've compacted it by using quantifier to restrict the occurrence of hyphen to just two only.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6GeDOH/1)**

If you want to extend your regex, just change `.*` to `[^-]*` to make your regex this, otherwise `.*` will match additional hyphens too leading to unexpected match results.

```
^([^-]*) - ([^-]*) - ([^-]*)$
```

Notice you should use start `^` and end `$` anchors to make the filename match whole regex.

**[Demo with your modified regex](https://regex101.com/r/6GeDOH/2)**

Comment: That worked PERFECTLY. Thank you so much, especially for the explanation.

Comment: @ScottCoats: Pleased to help :) Also please consider accepting my answer if it helped you. You get +2 rep and it will help people looking for solutions to similar posts.